# Understanding Haywards trapping gravity

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes

In the paper [General Laws of Black hole Dynamics](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.49.6467), Hayward has proposed a formula for trapping gravity of an outer trapping horizon given by

$\kappa$ = $\frac{1}{2}$ $\sqrt{-e^f \mathcal{L}_- \Theta_+}$ $\bigg|_H$

In the above mentioned paper, Hayward has defined surface gravity to be this, but I couldnt find any reasoning for why this quantity is nothing but surface gravity. My question is,  how do we know this quantity given by the above formula is surface gravity?

Comment: You should specify what $f$, $\mathcal{L}_-$ and $\Theta_-$ are

Comment: @LolloBoldo $\mathcal L_-$ is the lie derivative along the ingoing null vector and $\Theta_+$ is the expansion of the outgoing null rays